# Missing bar/value on SSRS bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm having trouble with a missing bar on an SSRS bar chart. I've done a bunch of searches online to try to find solutions, but nothing I've tried seems to fix it, and I'm getting frustrated.

I have the following data (this is a screenshot of the query results run directly from the dataset in SSRS):

[image: SSRS Chart Data with Grades and Number of Students Per Grade]

And no matter what I do, the "Test" grade will not show up in the Chart:

[image: SSRS Bar Chart based on data in previous screenshot]

Actually, the original list of Grades didn't include "Unsatisfactory", and the "Test" grade still didn't appear.  I added the 4th grade to see if it would change which bar didn't appear, or to see if it was locked to a limited number of bars or something, but, as you can see, it included the new Grade, but it still leaves out "Test".

I've tried the following things, with no success:

1. Made sure there were NO chart or dataset filters set and the chart is not in a table or anything else that has filters (it's not filtering that Grade out by anything I can find)
2. Chart Axis Interval: =1
3. Chart Axis AllowLabelRotation = Rotate30 (in case the labels were too long or something...?)
4. Changed the size of the chart (in case there wasn't enough room for 4 bars)
5. Changed the label font size (in case the labels were too long or something...?)
6. Changed the name of the "Test" Grade from "Letter" (in case that was a reserved word or something), and also tried setting it to my name instead of "Test"

There's probably more that I've tried, but that's all I can remember at the moment.

Here's a screenshot of my chart settings -- the Expression is `=((Fields!TotalStudentsPerGrade.Value / Fields!TotalStudentsInClass.Value) * 100)` to get the percent:

[image: Chart Property settings window]

Comment: I don't think it would affect your issue but you shouldn't need to have the **Grade** as a series. I would try re-creating the chart from scratch - sometimes they get jacked up and it takes longer to figure out what property is making it work incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't understand why it's working now, but apparently, even though I checked that the query was returning all of those values and there were no filters anyhow, somehow something was ignoring one of the students that had that "test" score.  I added the "test" score to another student to see if it would show 2 when it wouldn't show 1, and it only showed 1.  Again, I tested the query and the "test" grade was showing in the dataset results, so I don't understand why the chart wouldn't have just shown it.

In any case, it's resolved, though I don't understand why it was broken in the first place.